# Yii2 Rules Validate When Condition

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, rules

I have form fields generated by Yii2 using echo $form->field. When I select 'Pay Now' and submit, the validation should NOT validate the payment person's last name. However, when I select 'Pay Later' and submit, it must validate it as required.

Regardless of what I select, it always treats the field as required. What am I doing wrong?

Select Option:

```
<select id="singleregisterform-paymentoptionid" name="SingleRegisterForm[paymentOptionId]">
    <option value="1">Pay Now</option>
    <option value="2">Pay Later</option>
</select>
```

Text Field:

```
<input type="text" id="singleregisterform-paymentpersonlastname" 
       name="SingleRegisterForm[paymentPersonLastname]" 
       maxlength="40" placeholder="Enter last name">
```

Yii2 Model Rules:

```
['paymentOptionId', 'required'],
['paymentPersonTitleId', 'required'],
['paymentPersonLastname', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 45],
['paymentPersonLastname', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
        return $model->paymentOptionId == 2;
    }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
        return $('#paymentOptionId').val() == 2;
}"],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a ‘whenClient’ rule

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#conditional-validation

Comment: Thanks Graig, I have updated the question with the whenClient part added. What it does now is to always make the paymentPersonLastname as valid, whether it has a value in it or not and no matter what the value of paymentoptionid is. If I select/change paymentoptionid to 1 or 2 on client side, the paymentPersonLastname is always valid, even with an empty string.

Comment: When I put this in alert($('#paymentOptionId').val()); the value is always undefined? So I had to change it to alert($('#singleregisterform-paymentoptionid').val()); then I get the value. Not sure what I am missing?

Comment: The correct Id selector is.  singleregisterform-paymentoptionid. Update the whenClient with this.